# How to handle this type of JSON data? (Object object)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

First I was facing object object when I try to display the JSON API through HTML, then I used keyvalue in *ngFor and it did display the object, but how can I access to the whole data in json and display it?

codes:
HTML

```
   <mat-option *ngFor="let nitem of organizations | keyvalue"  [value]="nitem.key">
      {{ nitem.key }} {{nitem.value}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
  this.s.qOrganizations(qOrganizationsParams, this.localqAuthorization)
    .subscribe(data =>
      {
        this.organizations = data.data;
        this.oorganizations = data.data;
      console.log("Organization:",this.organizations)
                       


  }
      
  );
```

JSON DATA:

```
"data": {
"region": {
    "2": {
        "name": "test123",
        "license_number": "1111",
        "telephone": "167787",
        "mobile": "980980",
        "email": "example",
        "city": "Jeddah"
    },
```

How can I display "region" and "name"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are having several objects inside `region` property, so I would actually make an array of that, something like:

```
  arr = [];

  data = {
    region: {
      '1': {
        name: 'test2',
        license_number: '1111',
        telephone: '167787',
        mobile: '980980',
        email: 'example',
        city: 'Jeddah'
      },
      '2': {
        name: 'test3',
        license_number: '1111',
        telephone: '167787',
        mobile: '980980',
        email: 'example',
        city: 'Jeddah'
      }
    }
  }

ngOnInit() {
  for (let key in this.data.region) {
    this.arr.push(this.data.region[key]);
  }
}
```

And then display the array in template instead:

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let nitem of arr" [value]="nitem.name">
     Region {{nitem.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example below assumes you have parsed the JSON to JS as `data`.

First obtain the region name by looking at first key in region object, then use this to access name property:

```js
const regionName = Object.keys(data)[0];

const name = data.region[`${regionName}`].name
```